# Is Super.com legit?

Tags: online-resources, accommodation-search-engines

Trying to find nice but cheap accommodation for my wife and I.  Usually we'd book on something like Expedia, Hotels.com, or similar, but one of my searches yesterday came up with a handful of results through SuperTravel (super.com), and I've never heard of them.  A quick look at their [BBB profile](https://www.bbb.org/us/ca/san-francisco/profile/hotel-reservation/supertravel-1116-881071) seems to indicate they're legit, but I also don't want to be handing over hundreds of dollars to find I've got no booking at all.

Currently leaning towards booking elsewhere, unless there is evidence that SuperTravel is worth using.